# user value in textfield become wrong while viewing

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, uipickerview

I am new to IOS i created textfield for enter value in integer.That integer convert into string then it  can be passed to Post method and finally button action it can be viewed in alert view.if user given value to textfield means its value going wrong but constant value is given means its showing correct value i  am struggling to get correct value when user enter in textfield.

Post method:
below coding showing post method with parameter(str)passing

```
-(void) sendDataToServer : (NSString *) method params:(NSString *)str{

    NSData *postData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[str length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if( theConnection ){

        mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}
```

picker view:

```
- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

{
    if(pickerView.tag ==2){
    txtText.text = (NSString *)[arrMsg objectAtIndex:row];
        branchid1 = (NSString *)[arrmsg1 objectAtIndex:row];

        NSLog([arrmsg1 objectAtIndex:row]);

    }else if(pickerView.tag ==1){
    currency1.text = (NSString *)[currencyname1 objectAtIndex:row];
        currencyid1 = (NSString *)[id1 objectAtIndex:row];
        NSLog([id1 objectAtIndex:row]);


    }
    else
    {
        currency2.text = (NSString *)[from_currency objectAtIndex:row];
        currencyid2 = (NSString *)[id2 objectAtIndex:row];
        NSLog([id2 objectAtIndex:row]);
    }
    //here i assign textfield value into string
    fourthstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value1.text];
   NSLog(@"%@",value1.text);
  //here i created str as string to pass parameter to post method
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"branch_id=%@&from_curr=%@&to_curr=%@&value=%@",branchid1,currencyid1,currencyid2,fourthstr];
   [self sendDataToServer :@"POST" params:str];

}
```

Comment: in here you get  fourthstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value1.text];
   NSLog(@"%@",value1.text); wrong value

Comment: ya correct there only i am  getting wrong value @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: if i put direct value as 55 means "fourthstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",55];" its showing correct answer @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: explain some failure scenario

Comment: if i give  direct integer value to fourthstr means its showing correct value@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: I agree your point , if you assign the value to textfield what the value you retrieve

Comment: otherwise if i passing textfield value means its showing wrong value @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: show some exaple related to this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111627/discussion-between-a-sonu-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: why are you using integer format specifier (%d) for the string value?

Comment: replace the line "fourthstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value1.text]" to  "fourthstr = value1.text", then it will work fine.